# Flip a coin $20$ times and record the sequence of heads and tails. How many sequences are there where you get heads on #$1$, #$4$,#$7$, and #$13$?

Tags: combinatorics

> You flip a coin $20$ times and record the ordered sequence of heads and tails. How many sequences are there in which you get heads on (at least) flip #$1$, #$4$,#$7$, and #$13$?

If these spots are fixed with $h$, then I have $16$ spots left with each two choices. Wouldn't the answer then be $2^{16}$ as that's the number of ways I can  fill the remaining spots?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: Another approach to the same answer is that if this was a fair coin then originally there would have been $2^{20}$ possibilities but this particular event had a probability of $\frac1{2^4}$